# How many services for the Media Player?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am currently working through the [MediaPlayer Playback documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#asyncprepare) and find it hard to understand the role of Services and Event Listeners in this case. Generally, it seems to be a good idea to use a service for wrapping the Media Player.

Then again, there are two examples for implementing the Event Listeners:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener

...
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
```

In each case there is a media player object which I find confusing, shouldn't there be like one service to wrap the media player and then reigster event handlers to it and not by using an additonal service each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Java` any object can have multiple interfaces, so you can use something like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, 
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
```

In such a case single `Service` get all the functionality you need. The idea of using service is very simple: you would like to listen the music even if you've swiched to another app. Activities are used to interact with users via UI, no heavy jobs or long-running jobs should be done there.